# How to read a markdown file in another markdown file?

Tags: markdown

My purpose is to collect many descriptions written in markdown to a single markdown file for an integrated article.

For instance, in ./f1/a.md

```
This is the description for f1 project.
```

and in ./b.md

```
The introduction of f1 project is shown below, 
<!-- Contain of the a.md goes here -->
```

The expected result of the b.md should be,

```
The introduction of f1 project is shown below, 
This is the description for f1 project.
```

So, how can I achieve this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Markdown itself doesn't support file inclusions, but depending on the Markdown processor you are using you've got a couple of options:

- Some Markdown processors support multiple input files. For example, [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/) can take multiple input files and generate a single output file:

  ```
  pandoc -o output.html one.md two.md three.md
  ```
- You could simply concatenate your individual source files together in the correct order, then use that concatenated file as a single input for a less flexible parser:

  ```
  cat one.md two.md three.md > source.md
  markdown source.md
  ```

  If you are on Windows you will probably need to replace `cat` with `type`.

  Depending on the complexity of your input, you may want to automate this process. A tool like [`make`](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/) could help with this.