# Is there a markdown equivalent to LaTeX's 'input' command (that could be used in a jupyter notebook)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, latex, markdown

I'm working on a collaborative document with clearly separated sections. Let's say each person is only working on one section each. Pushing changes to github.

I'd like to be able to pull all these sections together into a single document.

In LaTeX I would use the ['\input' or '\include'](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246/when-should-i-use-input-vs-include) commands. Is there anything like this in markdown?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Markdown and including multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779582/markdown-and-including-multiple-files)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read a markdown file in another markdown file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28294926/how-to-read-a-markdown-file-in-another-markdown-file)